# Performance issue with Linq to object taking more time

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml code which is getting updated based on the object value. The 'foreach' loop here is taking almost 12-15 minutes to fetch a 200 kb xml file. Please suggest how I can improve the performance. (the xml file consists of a four leveled tag in which the child (4th level) tags are each 10 in number)

Code:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xmlDoc.Descendants();
foreach (DataSource Data in DataLst)
{ 
    XElement xmlElem = (from xmlData in elements
                        where Data.Name == xmlData.Name.LocalName  //Name
                           && Data.Store == xmlData.Element(XName.Get("Store", "")).Value
                           && Data.Section == xmlData.Element(XName.Get("Section", "")).Value
                        select xmlData.Element(XName.Get("Val", ""))).Single();

    xmlElem.ReplaceWith(new XElement(XName.Get("Val", ""), Data.Value));
}
```

Comment: `xmlData.Element(XName.Get("XYZ", ""))` can be written as `xmlData.Element("XYZ")`. A lot more readable.

Comment: It's not *fetching* any files at all. The timing does seem *very* strange though. Can you reproduce this in a short but complete program  we can all try ourselves? (I would also start just using the string conversion to `XName` rather than `XName.Get`, just for simplicity.)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an O(n)×O(m) issue here, for n = size of DataList and m = size of the xml. To make this O(n)+O(m), you should index the data; for example:

```
var lookup = elements.ToLookup(
       x => new {
            Name = x.Name.LocalName,
            Store = x.Element(XName.Get("Store", "")).Value,
            Section =  x.Element(XName.Get("Section", "")).Value},
       x =>  x.Element(XName.Get("Val", ""))
    );

foreach (DataSource Data in DataLst)
{ 
    XElement xmlElem = lookup[
          new {Data.Name, Data.Store, Data.Section}].Single();
    xmlElem.ReplaceWith(new XElement(XName.Get("Val", ""), Data.Value));
}
```

(untested - to show general approach only)

Comment: This is the approach I would take. I've going to guess that this approach will take less than 15 seconds to complete.

Answer (score 1):

i think better approach would be to Deserialize XML to C# Classes and then use LINQ on that, should be fast.

Answer (score 1):

"Well thanks everyone for your precious time and effort"

Problem answer: Actually the object 'DataLst' was of the type IEnumerable<> which was taking time in obtaining the values but after I changed it to the List<> type the performance improved drastically (now running in 20 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

If it really takes this long to run this, then maybe do something like this:

1. Don't iterate both - only iterate the XML-File and load the Data from your DataLst (make a SQL-command or simple linq-statement to load the data based on Name/Store/Section), make a simple struct/class for your key with this data (Name/Store/Section) - don't forget to implement equals, and GetHashCode
2. iterate through your XML-Elements and use the dictionary to find the values to replace

This way you will only iterate the XML-File once not once for every data in your DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why it's taking that long - that's a *very* long time. How many elements are in `DataLst`? I would rewrite the query for simplicity to start with though:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xmlDoc.Descendants();
foreach (DataSource data in DataLst)
{ 
    XElement valElement = (from element in xmlDoc.Descendants(data.Name)
                           where data.Store == element.Element("Store").Value
                              && data.Section == element.Element("Section").Value
                           select element.Element("Val")).Single();

    valElement.ReplaceWith(new XElement("Val"), data.Value));
}
```

(I'm assuming none of your elements *actually* have namespaces, by the way.)

Next up: consider replacing the *contents* of `valElement` instead of replacing the element itself. Change it to:

```
valElement.ReplaceAll(data.Value);
```

Now, this has all been trying to keep to the simplicity of avoiding precomputation etc... because it *sounds* like it shouldn't take this long. However, you *may* need to build lookups as Marc and Carsten suggested.

Comment: the declaration is :                                             private IEnumerable<DataDS> DataLst = null;  and there are almost 316 elements in DataLst.

Comment: @spins3: That doesn't help me to work out how many items it has in the case that's taking a long time...

Comment: @spins3: Right - then it sounds like it's taking *way* longer than I'd expect. If you take out the ReplaceWith/ReplaceAll call, does that make it any faster?

Comment: Yeah if we have only one element in the DataLst then it takes 1 minute for the foreach loop.

Comment: @spins3: For a 220K file? That's crazy. Are you sure you don't have something else going on in the debugger which would be slowing things down? (Are you running this in the debugger or not?)

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing `Single()` call in the LINQ with `First()`.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of flaming, have you considered writing this in XQuery instead? There's a good chance that a decent XQuery processor would have a join optimiser that handles this query efficiently.